# Python Error: "The JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, not NoneType"

Tags: python, json, google-translate, google-translation-api

I am trying to translate a .srt subtitle file with python and googleTranslate module. I can't because I get this error: ***TypeError: the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, not NoneType***

This is my code:

```
from googletrans import Translator
import glob
import subprocess
import os
import json


f = open('/Users/agustinleira/Desktop/Series Mac/Outlander/Temporada 3/1.srt', 'r')
if f.mode == 'r':
    print("Hola")
    contents = f.read()
    #print(contents)
    #print((type(contents)))
    file_translate = Translator()
    #print(type(file_translate))
    #print(dir(file_translate))
    #text_file = json.dumps(contents)#"Hola todo bien" #str(contents)
    result = file_translate.translate(contents, dest='en')
    print(result.text)
```

This is an example of 1.srt file:

```
1
00:00:02,003 --> 00:00:03,004
Narrator: Previously...

2
00:00:03,129 --> 00:00:05,047
The battle of culloden
will happen... today.

3
00:00:05,131 --> 00:00:06,757
Just as history foretold.

4
00:00:07,175 --> 00:00:08,801
Jamie: And we must go now.
```

Could you help me?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You're making us guess where the error is.  Please update the question to include the full error traceback.

Comment: Although if you give us the full error trace, we'll only be able to tell you what it's already telling you. The error message is pretty self explanatory, if you just go to where it happened and see why that value is None. Sometimes you're just missing a validation check "if X:"

Comment: `if f.mode == 'r'` seems pointless; you just opened the file with mode `'r'`, and it won't have changed by the next line.

Comment: Also, you are leaking the file handle. Use the contextmanager or remember to close the file.

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing wrong with your code. It's an issue with the `googletrans` Python package. You can check more about this issue: https://github.com/ssut/py-googletrans/issues/354

`googletrans` package was updated almost 2 years ago. I would suggest you to use some other translation package that's up to date with latest changes in Google Translate.

Comment: Thank you for answer me. When I changed the module for: from translate import Translator and file_translate = Translator(from_lang="english",to_lang="spanish") 

I get this error: 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/agustinleira/Desktop/Python/translate_test_2.py", line 19, in <module>
    result = file_translate.translate(contents)
  File "/Users/agustinleira/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/translate/translate.py", line 45, in translate
    return ' '.join(self.provider.get_translation(text_wraped) for text_wraped in text_list)
RuntimeError: generator raised

Comment: @user3319338 Can you share your code? You can hse some pastebin service like pastebin.com or privatebin.net

Comment: Sure, you can see there: https://pastebin.com/vXgvcpV9